# What does "kurzheinig" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "kurzheinig" mean?

Example (from [here](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/4995/1)):

> Das niedrig gewachsene, schmalschultrige, breithüftige und kurzheinige Geschlecht das schöne nennen konnte nur der vom Geschlechtstrieb umnebelte männliche Intellekt

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It definitely is a typo (or likely an OCR error from scanning of Fraktur) since we can read the following in a contemporary publication:

[image]

<sup>[Arthur Schopenhauer: Sämtliche Werke in zwölf Bänden](http://books.google.com/books?id=EZXPecvrM9sC&dq=Arthur%20Schopenhauer%20%22breith%C3%BCftige%20und%20kurzbeinige%20Geschlecht%22&pg=PA296#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sup>

> Das niedrig gewachsene, schmalschultrige, breithüftige und **kurzbeinige** Geschlecht[...]

Answer (score 9):

It is a misspelling of "kurzbeinig", i.e. having short legs.  Probably the OCR made a mistake.

Answer (score 7):

It's a typo (or rather an [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) glitch). Should be "kurzbeinig" - short-legged.